# Why when cloning project, "python setup.py install" doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I append *setup.py* to my project.
I can install a package with this command as well:

```
pip install git+http://github.com/MrMahdi313/GapBot
```

But when clone project and use this command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Just installed require package and doesn't install my main package.

What's problem?

Comment: any relevant parts of an errorlog to share?

Comment: Works for me. The package is installed into `site-packages/GapBot-0.0.3-py3.5.egg`. (I used Python 3.5).

Comment: What are `pip -V` and `python -V` commands returning?

Comment: Yes installed site-packages/GapBot-0.0.3-py3.5.egg.
But i cant import GapBot. 
When i use this command:
`pip install git+repo`
Install `GapBot-0.0.3-py3.5.egg` and GapBot.
But when install from `setup.py install` just add `GapBot-0.0.3-py3.5.egg` and cant import package in another files. @phd

Comment: i dont get any error. @ZF007

Comment: these are use same version of python. @hoefling

Comment: But it is Python 3.6 or newer? Also, what error do you get on import? If you run `pip show GapBot | grep -i location` and then `unzip -l /path/to/egg`, are the sources listed? The more information you provide, the easier it is to find the real issue.

Comment: yes package require py 3.6 or higher.

Comment: Works for me. The commands: `git clone https://github.com/MrMahdi313/GapBot.git && cd GapBot && python setup.py install && python -c "import gapbot"` works and produces no errors.

Comment: Yeah its ok.
i used old version of pycharm and this is a pycharm's bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bug of pycharm.
I updated pycharm and fixed.